# Perform code when unwind segue with back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, unwind-segue

I want to perform some code when the segue goes back one step. For example, when the back button gets selected, I want to perform some code.

I can't create a new unwind action from the back button because there is no back button in the storyboard. Is there a way to insert code, as soon as the back button is selected?

Comment: You could use `viewWillDisappear` if you can only go back from that particular view (otherwise it would be called when going back and forward in the view hierarchy).

Comment: I can't do that, because I will also be going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with the default back button, one way to do this is to subclass the navigation controller, and override popViewControllerAnimated: which is called when you tap the back button.

```
-(UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIViewController *vcToBePopped =[super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
    id vc = self.viewControllers.lastObject; // this will be the controller you're going back to
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:IntendedViewController class]) { // replace IntendedViewController with the actual class name you care about
        [(IntendedViewController *)vc someMethod];
    }

    return vcToBePopped;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a method called `popViewController`. If you're trying to say I should add a new one, where should it be called?

Comment: @MikeRally, I didn't say there was a method called popViewController, I said popViewControllerAnimated:, and there is such a method. Have you looked at the UINavigationController class reference?

Comment: Xcodes intelegent inspector is not picking it up. I checked the docs, and as you said it did have it. So I'm not sure what's going on?

Comment: Oh. I didn't subclass the navigation controller. But when I try my class at `intendedViewController`, it doesn't pick the class up? (And I did import it)

Comment: @MikeRally, I don't know why it wouldn't find it, as long as you imported it, and spelled it correctly.